# H2 Syntax error in SQL statement "... [*]limit ?"

Tags: spring-boot, h2

**H2 version: h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214**

I'm using JPQL for some queries in my app and i dont understand why i got the error:

> **SQL Error: 42000, SQLState: 42000; 
>
> Syntax error in SQL statement "select t.code as col_0_0_ from
> test t [*]limit ?";**

My JPQL query:

**@Query("SELECT t.code FROM Test t")
Page test(Pageable pageable);**

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: How do you configure h2? What actual db is h2 simulating?

Comment: @samabcde 
thanks alot for your question for me its was very helpful. I sloved my problem
i have two configuration first jdbc:h2:mem:myDb; second  jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;MODE=MSSQLServer;, 
configuration was override by MSSQLServer and here was a mistake